# Uniform Boundedness of a sequence of functions.

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading a book where it is stated that $$n\log(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})-\sqrt{n}x \leq -cx^2$$
for some $c>0$ when $|x| \leq\sqrt{n}$, and

$$n\log(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})-\sqrt{n}x \leq -cx\sqrt{n}$$
for $|x|>\sqrt{n}$, and I am confused on the distinction between the bounds $-cx^2$ and $-cx\sqrt{n}$.

I've attempted to prove the inequality first by showing that $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for $x=0$ and $x=\sqrt{n}$, then by calculating the derivative to show that $f(x)$ decreases faster than $g(x)$:

Let $f(x)=n\log(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})-\sqrt{n}x$ and $g(x)=-cx^2$.
The $x=0$ case is trivial.
Then, $$f(\sqrt{n})=n\log(1+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}})-\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}=n\log(2)-n\leq -cn \rightarrow$$ $$\log(2)-1 \leq -c$$ which is certainly true to some $c>0$.
Then $$f'(x)= -\frac{\sqrt{n}x}{\sqrt{n}+x} \leq -\frac{1}{\sqrt{n} +x} \leq -2cx = g'(x)$$

$$\rightarrow -\frac{1}{x\sqrt{n} +x^2} \leq -2c$$

Which is also certainly true for some choice of $c>0$.
So why is the author distinguishing between the bounds $-cx^2$ and $-cx\sqrt{n}$ at the point $x=\sqrt{n}$?
The boundedness is needed to use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: In the domain $|x|<\sqrt n$, we have $x^2 < |x| \sqrt n$, whereas in the other region the inequality is reversed. Hence, without looking into details, it seems to me the author is just trying to give the optimal bound in both regions.

Comment: But due to the negative sign, wouldn't $-|x|\sqrt{n}<-x^2$ for $|x|<\sqrt{n}$ make $-x^2$ the greater upper bound?

Comment: Similarly, for $|x|>\sqrt{n}$, $-x^2<-|x|\sqrt{n}$? I think you're right that the author is trying to give the most optimal bound, despite that $-cx^2$ is the only one needed to be proven to use Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Thm (as in i've showed pointwise convergence of the sequence to $-\frac{x^2}{2}$.